# example of an custom async js callback function

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to figure out about why/how some functions can be made async in nature in Javascript. Can someone please help me by providing some sort of example/explanation.

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand async function, you should understand what is [event loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ).

The easiest example:

```
window.setTimeout(function () { console.log('async'); }, 1);
```

But even the `console.log` is async. Check the video above and you will understand the basics.

Comment: Thank you so much. The video was awesome.